# Scrape array name tag and post all the tags as array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I use simple_html_dom to scrape the input fields from a page. The result of `$PostID->name;` is as like this:
price[4646464]price[565233]price[8989895] etc..

What I now need is those values to be posted with Curl. But I cant get it to be formatted right. I need to post all of these values to be as the following: action[4646464]:go (multiple times).

So I am trying to put this in a array but this is my var dump and I cant figur out how to get this structure right and if this is even posible with curl.

```
( [action] => Array ( [4646464] => go ) )
```

This should become and is the result i am looking for, if I am correct:

```
( [action] => Array ( action[4646464] => go, action[565233] => go,action[8989895] => go ) )
```

My tried code (after a lot of other failures..)

```
$ScrapedIdTopost = @$table->find('input');
foreach ($ScrapedIdTopost as $PostID) {

$PostIDStored =  @$PostID->name;
$PostIDStoredInt =  @filter_var($PostID->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);//To get the number
$NameTag = "action"; // to get the action tag before the [56565656] value

$postFields[$NameTag] = array($PostIDStoredInt => "go",);
echo $PostIDStored; // Shows up times the result scraped?
}
echo $PostIDStored; // Shows up only once?
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
print_r($postFields);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The link that I am posting to accepts the following post according to the network tab and this is what I am trying to accomplisch.

```
action[4646464]:go
action[565233]:go
action[8989895]:go
```

I am a bit new to coding and english is not my main language so I hope I explained this well and that there is someone that can help me because I am trying and searchring for hours now with no result.

UPDATE:

Tried it as suggested by @CBroe.

```
$ScrapedIdTopost = @$table->find('input');
foreach ($ScrapedIdTopost as $PostID) {


$PostIDStoredInt =  @filter_var($PostID->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$data = ['action' => [ $PostIDStoredInt => 'go',]];
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
//print_r($postData);
echo http_build_query($data);
```

It is still not working. First it only post one of the founded tags. I need al the founded tags posted, these are created dynamicly based on the rows the table has. The echo is as the folowing:

```
action%5B95420559%5D=go
```

So am I doing something wrong or is a other aproach needed?

Comment: `$action = [ '4646464' => 'go', '565233' => 'go', ... ];`

Comment: Thanks for respondig. But now only the number and go is posted. The request should be action[534664]:go.

Comment: If that's the case,  `$array = [ 'action[4646464]:go', ...]`?

Comment: I guess so. But that is my problem. How do I do that. I am searching for hours how to post this information like that. How to combine those values to have that result.

Comment: I mean we need more details here. You've placed a dump of the network tab, but what is the expected variable name the website is receiving? Also you want to create the postfields based on the `$ScrapedIdTopost ` array or not?

Comment: On the site it makes the post like this. in the form it has its atribute as the folwowing. name="action[]" value="go". So I scraped the id from the input tag and I need. So i can post repreduce the forms action with post name="action[$PostIDStoredInt]" and value = "sell". But I need to post for example 10 at the same time.

Comment: _"in the form it has its atribute as the folwowing. `name="action[]" value="go"`"_ - that would cause just `action[]=go` in the submitted data set, this would not specify any array index upfront explicitly. If this actually shows as `action[4646464]:go` in dev tools, then there must be additional JavaScript involved or something.

Comment: But either way, I would recommend that you use `http_build_query` for this. Built your data array in the proper forma, `$data = ['action' => [ '4646464' => 'go', '565233' => 'go' ]];` - and then pass `http_build_query($data)` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Thanks for responsing. Tried your solution and edited the question. Still no luck here:(

Comment: Now you are simply _overwriting_ your $data array in each loop iteration, so of course `$data['action']` will contain only one single element afterwards. `$data['action'][$PostIDStoredInt] = 'go';`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you give a bit fuller example. I want to learn but getting a bit lost here. Sorry new to coding

Comment: Can you please show me how to use your suggestion in my code? Tried it on diferent ways nothing has the right result.. Better yet all I echos is gogogogo.. The action and [$PostIDStoredInt] are empty.. Please can someone help, getting realy lost here

Comment: Is there someone that can help me? I have no idea what to do with all this. No matter how i try is it wont work.. Is what i am asking so dificult that no one knows or so simple that everyone thinks that I should know this. I am new so I dont know.